# Having problems with background image using Styles

Tags: css, html

having problem with background image with css on Mac Os.
if we change the resolution of browser it turn to look bad.i need look like same in every resol and also on Mac os.

**There is 2 section have bg image**

**using Mac os**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV5df.jpg

**using window os**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d69Yp.jpg

*I want to look like window os image on MAC.*

**code**

```css
.section-about {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/NlczAVu.jpg") top right/cover no-repeat;
    min-height: 545px;
  }

  /* line 180, ../sass/screen.scss */
  .section-experinece {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/eAeB5ci.jpg") top right/cover no-repeat;
    min-height: 1130px;
  }
  
  h1 {
  margin: 0;
  }
  
  .one {
  color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  p {
      margin: 0;

  }
```

```html
<section id="about" class="section-about">
    <h1>section1</h1>
                        <p clas="one">Lorem ipsum doeqw sitqwewqe amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus porta massa sit amet magna luctus euismod. Maurn malesuada nunc.  <span class="bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></p>
 <p clas="one">Lorem ipsum doeqw sitqwewqe amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus porta massa sit amet magna luctus euismod. Maurn malesuada nunc.  <span class="bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></p>
</section>

<section id="experinece" class="experinece-sec section-experinece">
    <h1>section2</h1>
             <p>Lorem ipsum doeqw sitqwewqe amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus porta massa sit amet magna luctus euismod. Maurn malesuada nunc.  <span class="bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></p>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum doeqw sitqwewqe amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus porta massa sit amet magna luctus euismod. Maurn malesuada nunc.  <span class="bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></p>
</section>
```

thanks.

Comment: please provide some example of code you have tried there is no link to jsfiddle, also what have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is not the  OS you are on, but the screen resolution you are viewing on.

Check the page on a windows machine and make the view as wide as you can.

[image: Viewed on windows, in IE]

Comment: it have perfect view on windows but not on the Mac. Maybe it is my css problem but not resolution problem.i want to look like same on any OS

Comment: @BilalBali it is definitely to do with resolution. Nothing to do with OS.

Comment: so its mean all about resol.We can't fix with css?

Comment: but i checked on mac its look different btw windows.

Comment: Listen to @JasperZelf. The way to position that shape is rather clumsy. Consider making the shape with CSS only.

Comment: The problem arises because you have set the background-size to "cover".
That will scale the background image and as a result it will no longer lign up with the upper background image. Is you want to fix this using the background images, that's where you want to start changing things. 

However, a pure CSS solution would be better, like @Dominik already mentioned. 

I'd check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ to see how you can make the shapes using pure CSS. Than it's just a matter of positioning them.

Comment: You right @Dominik but it is more difficult to handle the content and responsive view to using different shapes with css that you mention up.that's why i want to use images

Comment: @Bilal Bali This should get you started: https://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/6hds1zno/

If you want to change the dimentions when the browser's dimentions change, you can use a percentage or VH/VW units for sizing and positioning the triangles.

Comment: @JasperZelf i get it but i'm using bootstrap with column and if we used background shapes then the template looks responsiveness on tablet or mobile screen.

Comment: @JasperZelf please check this link.it is background image and i used it with body bg and section bg but it is not comfy.
http://i.imgur.com/jjpC2wR.jpg
**what you think about image**

Comment: Don't quite see the problem you are having with the responsiveness. Updated my fiddle to include responsiveness in the triangles. https://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/6hds1zno/1/

Comment: Sorry, I just don't get what you are trying to achieve. 
If you want a background image that covers the whole body, you should put the background image on the body. Unless you can describe exactly what it is you are aiming for, I can't help you.